# Drupal external persistent login

Tags: users, bootstrapping

I'm working on a project with a Drupal and a PhpBB section and I'm trying to create a single sign-on using the PhpBB login. When a user logs into PhpBB, he should also get logged in to Drupal. Vice versa is not needed.

I know you can bootstrap Drupal and use the external functions of the user module, but bootstrapping Drupal fully into PhpBB isn't a good idea so I was wondering if there are any other methods doing this.

I also tried out the Services module with the login API request, but the problem here is that the session isn't persistent. When I curl my details to the API, I get a nice json result with a session id, but I can't just keep passing the session id around in the PhpBB section not knowing wether and when the user will get back to the Drupal section.

I also worked with the Phpbbforum module, which worked a little bit but was a hassle if I wanted to do more advanced stuff. It also had a few bugs and issues (for example: the user synchronization would work one way, but not the other way around) so this module is not an option.

Thanks in advance, Tom.

Comment: "session isn't persistent"? You mean only problem with this approach is that user gets logged out when he closes tab with Drupal in it?

Comment: No: when I curl post the data using the services API, I get a logged in result with my account data. However, when I browse to my Drupal website, I am not logged in. (Obviously because the session doesn't get passed to my browser, so using this API approach isn't a good solution.)

Comment: Consider reading code of [Token Authentication](https://drupal.org/project/tokenauth) - I don't think it's a ready made solution for you, but serves similar purpose and ways it's using should work for you too.